# SharePoint. How to change default values in Ribbon

Tags: sharepoint, ribbon

I am using SharePoint 2010. When I insert an image into my content I see that spaces are added around the image. The spaces have default value 5px.

[image: 5px is default values for spaces]

I would like to have 0px instead. The reason is that editors forget to set it to 0px manually and basically do not want to make the extra step.

I have found that in SharePoint core there is 14\template\features\publishinglayouts\provisionedui.xml file where the default values for spaces are set. I do not like an idea to make changes in the file at all because:

- a. well it is core file and it could be changed in future by a
  service pack for instance
- b. I need to think about how to deploy the
  changed file to a farm (I can create a feature which will replace the
  file on all servers, but it sounds like a dirty hack).

Do you have better (or just any) ideas how can I achieve my goal?

Answer (score 0):

not really sure about it but can you just change the interval from 5 to 0 on that xml file?

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I can do it in provisionedui.xml. It means that I have to deploy my own changed provisionedui.xml which is, actually, a SharePoint core file. Deployment of the core files does not sound as a good solution.